# Windows 10 Store Downloads Failing

Tags: windows-10, windows-store

I'm trying to download an app I purchased on the Windows App Store, but the download is failing with error code 0x8004804e. Updating already installed Microsoft applications works, but I can't download any other applications.

Is this a permissions issue? I'm not the administrative user on the machine.

Update: forgot to mention I'm going through a proxy server which allows only ports 80 and 443.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer on a Microsoft [help site](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_store/windows-store-error-unable-to-download-apps-try/9187897f-8b79-4b26-a7bd-c210e679353d?auth=1).

```
netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie
```

Windows Store was not reading the proxy settings correctly from the environment.